# Writing unit test with JUnit and Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a method in service layer for saving an item to database. This method first checks if there is an item with the same name in database. If there is, then it throws an exception with a message, if there is not then it just saves the new item. Here is the code;

```
public TodoList saveTodoList(TodoList todoList) {
    List<TodoList> match = StreamSupport.stream(getAllTodoLists().spliterator(), false)
            .filter(list -> list.getName().equals(todoList.getName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    if (match.size() > 0)
        throw new ExistingDataException("Todo List already exists!");
    else
        return todoListRepository.save(todoList);
}
```

I am trying to learn testing with JUnit 5 and Mockito and I am a bit confused about what to test in general. How many tests should I write for this method? Do I need to test stream(I don't even know how)? How can you decide what to test in a method?

Edit: Here is my test class and test methods for the save method;

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class TodoListServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private ITodoListRepository todoListRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private TodoListService todoListService;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Should save the list to the repository")
    public void whenGivenTodoListDoesNotExistInDatabase_ThenSaveNewList() {
        TodoList mockList = mock(TodoList.class);
        mockList.setId(1);
        mockList.setName("List 1");

        when(todoListRepository.save(any(TodoList.class))).thenReturn(mockList);

        TodoList actual = todoListService.saveTodoList(mockList);

        assertEquals(mockList.getId(), actual.getId());
        assertEquals(mockList.getName(), actual.getName());
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Should throw exception if there is a list with given item's name")
    public void shouldThrowExistingDataException_IfThereIsAList_WithTheSameName() {
        TodoList mockList = mock(TodoList.class);
        mockList.setId(1);
        mockList.setName("List 1");

        Throwable actualException = assertThrows(ExistingDataException.class,
        () -> {
            todoListService.saveTodoList(mockList);
        });

        assertTrue(actualException.getMessage().contains("Todo List already exists!"));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to answer some of the questions that you have asked:

**How many tests should I write for this method?:** Essentially while writing test cases for a function or piece of code, there is no limit on how many test cases you should write. Generally you try to test atleast 1 positive flow and 1 negative flow. If your piece of code has many edge cases, then probably check those as well.

**Do I need to test stream(I don't even know how)? :** No. Stream is inbuilt java feature, you don't test inbuilt features. You just test your logic.

**How can you decide what to test in a method?:** As I mentioned earlier, you generally test positive flows and negative flows including any edge cases. For the above function it seems you have 1 positive and 1 negative flow. Your positive scenario could be where you expect value to not be present in your database and successfully store the data and your negative scenario can be when that data is already present you throw an exception. These are two minimum test cases you should write.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now I am trying to write assertThrows method for the negative scenario but I couldn't figure how to write the second parameter. I mean I need to write a lambda expression that actually throws the exception, right? But the code that actually throws the exception is the if statement. I didn't understand the logic here. Any suggestions?

Comment: You essentially have to write a assertThrows like below:
assertThrows(ExistingDataException.class, () -> todoListobject.saveTodoList(todoList));

todoListObject is the object of the class where your function resides.
todoList will be a mock / dummy object that you will have to create.
Also if you are using the actual repository to persist data while testing, would be better to persist a todo record in the database that has the same name property as your dummy todo object. 

Would be helpful if you can post the positive code sample here.

Comment: Edited the post as you requested. I use H2 database but I don't use actual data while testing. I use a mock repository. I organized the second test method as you suggested but it doesn't work. It says "Expected com.erdemkara.todoapp.exception.ExistingDataException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown."

Comment: If my assumption is correct, the function getAllTodoLists() probably calls your todoRepository to return all values in that particular table in the database. 
If that is the case, could you please try to do something like below:
when(todoRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(listOfTodos));
Where listOfTodos is a list that already contains a todo object with the name property as "List 1"

This needs to be added before the statement where you are calling actual service method in your test (before "Throwable actualException" statement)

Comment: Your assumption is correct, getAllTodoLists() method calls repository.findAll method. So I created an ArrayList in test method and added mock object to that arraylist. After that I added the behavior before "Throwable actualException" statement as you suggested;  
        List<TodoList> actualList = new ArrayList<>();
        actualList.add(mockList);

        when(todoListRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(actualList);

Now I'm getting NullPointerException instead of ExistingDataException and tests fails.

Comment: I think instead of TodoList mockList = mock(TodoList.class); 
You should create a new object like TodoList mockTodoList = new TodoList();
Then set your fields.
Rest of the implementation remains same. I am still trying to figure out the internals as to why we cannot mock the value object here. 
You can also use builders / factories to create dummy objects for tests
Also refer to below link on why we don't mock value / pojo objects

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/363112/is-it-really-a-bad-practice-to-mock-a-pojo-value-object-if-you-dont-care-abou

Comment: So it seems not mocking simple POJO objects is a better practice in our test code. I reorganized the code and created the TodoList object with new keyword. Now test passes. Appreciated for the answers @Ujwal, you've been a great help.